# statusCallbackEvent usage with Twilio in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have the following code in my Rails 4 app

```
call = client.account.calls.create(
  from: Rails.application.secrets.twilio_voice_number,
  to: phone_number,
  url: NGROK + question_path(question.id, @questionaire.notification.id),
  method: 'GET',
  statusCallback: NGROK + call_status_path(@questionaire.notification.id),
  statusCallbackEvent: [:ringing, :answered, :completed]
)
```

That all works. My `statusCallback` is firing and I can read `params[:CallStatus]` to get the status. I read in the Twilio documentation that I could also determine if any of the following have occurred

`busy`, `no-answer`, `cancelled` or `failed`

How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#call-status-values

Comment: @Зелёный - I'm after an example. If I pass `:busy` to `statusCallbackEvent` my `statusCallback` is not hit on a busy call.